# When aircraft is flown by the pilot and when by the autopilot? What are common procedures?

Tags: autopilot

I am courious about different phases of flight in which airplane is flown by the Pilot, and when by the Autopilot.

For example, I'm quite sure that generally pilots have full control during takeoff and landing (full control? stick and throttle?) but during cruise at high altitude is the autopilot that has control.

But when a pilot activates autopilot? immediately after takeoff? And when take control again?

Comment: What is your definition of autopilot? For example during take off and most of landing, autothrottle is used...

Comment: It depends a lot on the aircraft type, as well as the pilot, weather conditions, length and type of flight, etc.  This is a pretty broad question; like asking how often people use cruise control in their cars...

Comment: assuming you mean transport-type, most common type being asked about when not stated, see link above

Comment: @RonBeyer The ***autothrottle*** is considered to be a separate system than the ***autopilot***. They're both part of "the automation" and the FMCS and a few other things, but at least in the 737 world, the two terms are distinct and do not overlap.

Comment: I understand the overlap and distinction, but the OP *may* be lumping all computer flying under the broad "autopilot" term, which is why I asked if they want to specifically know "autopilot" or in more general computer control terms...